# Ethernet does not work after clean install of 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

this may seem like a dumb question, but I've searched dozens of askubuntu questions and tried many solutions to try to fix this problem, but none of them worked. I know this is an issue on Ubuntu's end because the ethernet consistently works with Windows on the exact same machine, but consistently doesn't work with Ubuntu. My ethernet is just a simple wire into my router. No static ips, no edited etc files, just clean install and an ethernet cable, and it simply does not work. However, a USB Wifi adapter does work. I am at a complete loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

System stats:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
CPU: Intel Core i7-4770
Motherboard: Dell Precision T1700
```

Results of `lshw -C network`

```
  *-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 19
    bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
    logical name: eno1
    version: 04
    serial: b8:ca:3a:8e:3f:36
    size: 1Gbit/s
    capacity: 1Gbits/s       
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list etherner physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.14-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
    resources: irq:29 memory:f3100000-f311ffff memory:f3139000-f3139fff ioport:f040(size=32)
```

Results of `dmesg`:

```
[69039.062133] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

Comment: run `dmesg`; plug in the cable; run it again; see what it says

Comment: Edit your question to include the relevant output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Don't paste the whole thing -- just the section on your ethernet interface.

Comment: @MaxB I edited in the results

Comment: @user535733 I edited in the results

Comment: What do your Settings/Network/Wired  settings show?  Connect automatically, available to all users, and ipv4 automatic and DNS set?

Comment: @user535733 That worked beautifully, thank you sooo much. If you have an XMR address, I'll send you some!